# How to Get a Polygon Collider Contact Point

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, polygon

```
 if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Ball")
        {  
            collision.GetContacts(contactPoints);

            Debug.Log(contactPoints[0].point.y);
        }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6aiv.png

If you've checked the image, you will notice that the point with the least y position in the polygon collider has "-1.445364", at the collision to the same point "+1.8" is being returned instead of the expected value which is "-1.445364".

The collision point x position seems to be accurate except the y.

I've also checked the World position of the object itself and it still doesn't match.

I need to know where this wrong number is coming from and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The [contact point](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PolygonCollider2D-points.html) returns the actual point of contact in world space. I mean, it's the point in world space where the collision between the two objects has occured.

The values under ["points"](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PolygonCollider2D-points.html) is in local space. You would have to calculate based on the collision contact point, the position of your object, which is the pivot point. Usually the centre of the object unless you have changed it.